# Complex numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ are collinear, show that there exist $a,b,c$ for which $ax+by+cz=0$ where $a+b+c=0$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> Suppose $x$, $y$, and $z$ are collinear (complex numbers). Prove that there exist real constants $a$, $b$, $c$, not all zero, such that $ax+by+cz=0$ where $a+b+c=0$.

This is how I did it:

First, since the points are collinear, $x-y=\lambda(x-z)$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Then distributing $\lambda$, moving $x$ and $z$ to the left hand side we end up with $$(1-\lambda)x-y+\lambda z=0$$
Meaning that $a=1-\lambda$, $b=-1$, and $c=\lambda$ satisfy the conditions above.

Is this valid?

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: Yes. Correct...

Comment: Oh okay thanks!